# RESTeasy HTTP proxy - SOCKS error

Tags: java, proxy, resteasy

I'm experiencing issues Java's useSystemProxy-Feature in combination with RESTeasy's ClientRequest class:

```
ClientRequest request = new ClientRequest(Config.getInstance().getProperty(Config.UPDATE_URL));
ClientResponse<FullscreenUpdateTransfer> response = request.get(FullscreenUpdateTransfer.class);
if (response.getStatus() != Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode())
{
    throw new Exception("HTTP Status Response: " + response.getStatus());
}
```

Throws after about a minute:

```
java.net.SocketException: Malformed reply from SOCKS server
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.readSocksReply(SocksSocketImpl.java:90)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:429)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:249)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:79)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:121)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:706)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:386)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:170)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:396)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:324)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.executors.ApacheHttpClientExecutor.execute(ApacheHttpClientExecutor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ClientExecutionContextImpl.proceed(ClientExecutionContextImpl.java:39)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.AcceptEncodingGZIPInterceptor.execute(AcceptEncodingGZIPInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ClientExecutionContextImpl.proceed(ClientExecutionContextImpl.java:45)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest.execute(ClientRequest.java:448)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest.httpMethod(ClientRequest.java:655)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest.get(ClientRequest.java:483)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest.get(ClientRequest.java:503)
    at de.taf.easygo.modules.dfimanager.database.logic.Update.run(Update.java:110)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)
```

So Apache HTTP Client seems to be told to use a SOCKS proxy by RESTeasy. (Now that I re-read the stack trace it rather seems Socket is ordered to use a SOCKS proxy by Apache HTTP Client.) Have been searching for a solution for a while now. I worked around it many times by using HttpUrlConnection and then manually give the result to a JaxbContext. Not very convenient, especially if it comes to PUT requests, so I'd like to ask if anybody solved this.

Of cause I'm using a tested/working HTTP proxy for this.

I DO NOT have the option to provide the proxy via proxyHost/proxyPort properties. I need to use java.net.useSystemProxies.